# Unable to generate Typeorm Migration. Error: No changes in database schema were found - cannot generate a migration

Tags: postgresql, webpack, nestjs, typeorm, nomachine-nx

I am using nestjs typeorm and nx workspace and using a webpack compiler

```
db.config.ts
export const  dataSourceOptions: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  port: +process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  entities: [
    __dirname + 'src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}',
  ],
  migrations: [
    __dirname + 'src/migrations/*.migration{.ts,.js}',
  ],
  extra: {
    charset: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
  },
  migrationsTableName: 'migrations_typeorm',
  migrationsRun: Boolean(process.env.DATABASE_MIGRATION_SYNC),
  synchronize: Boolean(process.env.DATABASE_SYNC),
  logging: Boolean(process.env.DATABASE_LOGGING)
}

const dataSource = new DataSource(dataSourceOptions);
export default dataSource;
```

```
Scripts
"typeorm": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "outputs": [],
      "options": {
        "command": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
      }
    },
    "db-migration-gen": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "outputs": [],
      "options": {
        "command": "nx run project:typeorm -- migration:generate -d apps/project/src/config/db.config.ts apps/project/src/migrations/{args.name}"
      }
    },
    "db-migration-create": {
      "dependsOn": [
        {
          "target": "build",
          "projects": "self"
        }
      ],
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "outputs": [],
      "options": {
        "command": "nx run project:typeorm -- migration:create apps/project/src/migrations/{args.name}"
      }
    },
    "db-migration-run": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "outputs": [],
      "options": {
        "commands": ["rimraf dist", "nx run project:typeorm -- -d apps/project/src/config/db.config.ts migration:run"]
      }
    },
```

Here db-migration-create and db-migration-run is running fine but in case of db-migration-gen I am getting below mentioned error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1SuJ.png)

I tried various fixed with typeorm documentation but I was only able to fix create and run but generate is still throwing error

Comment: it looks more like something is wrong with the configurations pipeline that causes the final `typeorm` command to not be what you want it to be. try to run typeorm generate command directly to verify that it is indeed not a typeorm issue. if not, the generate command should work

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue came from the regex `'src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'` as with webpack you should probably build to "dist" folder. You have to consider two configurations, one for development and one for the production mode.

I suggest 2 solutions for this issue :

- Do as the [FAQ](https://typeorm.io/faq#bundling-migration-files) said and adapt that code with "Entities". You should then have all your entities compiled in one folder then use this.
- Adapt import directly each entity like `entities: [User, Post, ...]` instead of using the regex. ( I prefer this one )

I think your command `db-migration-run` is running, but do not run your migrations and considering it empty or it looks for migration in `src/` that is not what you want in many cases. You should follow the FAQ.
It's possible then that you have an error "Metadata not found" using typeorm and webpack depending on your configuration. But this will be another problem.

Hope it will help.